# Length of curve on $(S^2,\tilde g)$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Under the polar coordinate, the unit sphere is
$$
S^2=\{(\sin\theta\cos\varphi,\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\theta)\in \mathbb R^3:\theta\in[0,\pi],\varphi\in[0,2\pi] \}
$$
consider a non-induced metric, for example,
$$
\tilde g =\begin{pmatrix}
f(\theta,\varphi) &0 \\
0 & h(\theta,\varphi)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And a curve on $S^2$
$$
r(t)=(\cos t,\sin t \cos K, \sin t \sin K),  t\in[0,\pi]
$$
then how to calculate the length of $r(t)$?  The $K>0$ is constant.

What I try: Let
$$
r(\theta,\varphi)= (\sin\theta\cos\varphi,\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\theta)
$$
then,
$$
\langle  r_{\theta},r_{\theta}\rangle = f(\theta,\varphi)  \\
\langle  r_{\varphi},r_{\varphi}\rangle = h(\theta,\varphi)
$$
Besides, I have
$$
r'(t)=(-\sin t, \cos t \cos K, \cos t\sin K)
$$
But I don't know how to use $r_\theta,r_\varphi$ to present $r'(t)$. Therefore, I can't calculate the $|r'(t)|_{\tilde g}$.

Comment: For the standard metric
$$
g=d\theta\otimes d\theta+\sin^2\theta\,d\varphi\otimes d\varphi
$$
you calculate the length of a curve $t\mapsto (\theta(t),\varphi(t))$ by
$$
\int_0^t\sqrt{\dot\theta^2+(\sin^2\theta)\,\dot\varphi^2}\,dt\,.
$$
For your metric $\tilde g=f\,d\theta\otimes d\theta+h\,d\varphi\otimes d\varphi$ the length is accordingly
$$
\int_0^t\sqrt{f\,\dot\theta^2+h\,\dot\varphi^2}\,dt\,.
$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of curve in 3D spherical coordinate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328203/length-of-curve-in-3d-spherical-coordinate)

Comment: @KurtG.  I think they are different.  It is not standard metric. Therefore, $\int \sqrt{\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)+\dot z^2(t)}\ dt$ is useless. I think I need to find suitable $\theta(t),\varphi(t)$ such that $r(\theta(t),\varphi(t))=(\cos t,\sin t \cos K, \sin t \sin K)$. Then, using your third formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the standard metric
$$
g=d\theta\otimes d\theta+\sin^2\theta\,d\varphi\otimes d\varphi
$$
you calculate the length of a curve $t\mapsto (\theta(t),\varphi(t))$ by
$$
\int_0^t\sqrt{\dot\theta^2+(\sin^2\theta)\,\dot\varphi^2}\,dt\,.
$$
For your metric $\tilde g=f\,d\theta\otimes d\theta+h\,d\varphi\otimes d\varphi$ the length is accordingly
$$
\int_0^t\sqrt{f\,\dot\theta^2+h\,\dot\varphi^2}\,dt\,.
$$
If the curve you are considering is given in ambient space $\mathbb R^3$ by
$$
r(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t\\\sin t\cos K\\\sin t\sin K\end{pmatrix}
$$
then you find its $S^2$ coordinates $(\theta(t),\varphi(t))$ from
\begin{align}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi&=\cos t\,,\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi&=\sin t\cos K\,,\\
\cos\theta&=\sin t\sin K\,.
\end{align}
The solution for $\theta,\varphi$ does not look pretty but is straightforward.